# MongoDB - How to set $gte and $lte options in .find() method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is a table that has a `year` field. (string type)

At this table, I'd like to search some rows between `$gte` and `$lte`.

If the rows are like these:

```
[
  {
    "year": "2022"
  },
  {
    "year": "2023"
  },
  {
    "year": "2024"
  },
  {
    "year": "2024"
  },
  {
    "year": "2025"
  },
  {
    "year": "2026"
  },
  {
    "year": "2028"
  },
  {
    "year": "2030"
  },
  {
    "year": "2036"
  }
]
```

I'd like to search the values between 2022 and 2025.

For that purpose, I wrote the code like this.

```bash
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        $toInt: "$year"
      },
      2022
    ],
    $lte: [
      {
        $toInt: "$year"
      },
      2025
    ]
  }
})
```

But, this error occurred.

> query failed: (Location15983) An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $gt: [ { $toInt: "$year" }, 2022.0 ], $lte: [ { $toInt: "$year" }, 2025.0 ] }

Could you tell me the solution to this problem?

Additionally, I tested it in this environment.
[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kGz8yRFGq_h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss out the `$and` operator. And wrap `$gte` and `$lte` with a `{}` respectively.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gt: [
          {
            $toInt: "$year"
          },
          2022
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          {
            $toInt: "$year"
          },
          2025
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YJ9RoISJiUI)

Comment: Oh, and option was missing! Thank you so much